# Poitwise limit of a monotonically increasing function sequence in $L^p(M)$ exists always almost everywhere

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, lp-spaces

I am having trouble comprehending the following remark made in my function analysis text.

> Let $\left(f_n\right)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of functions in $L^p(M), 1 \leq p < \infty$ and assume that $0 \leq f_{n} \leq f_{n + 1}$ $\mu$-a.e. in $M$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Then the pointwise limit $f = \lim_{n\to \infty}f_n$ exists $\mu$-a.e. in $M$.

What I don't understand is that what exactly guarantees the existence? The function sequence $f_n = n\cdot 1_{[0, 1]}$ in e.g. $L^p(\mathbb{R})$ satisfies the criterions but $\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n := \infty \cdot 1_{[0, 1]}$ seems a bit dubious.

Comment: You are right. It is probably implied that $f$ can equal $+\infty$ on a set of positive measure. Indeed, they say "the limit exists", which IS true if you stipulate that $\infty$ is a limit.

Comment: You may consider the sequence $g_{n,a,b}={f_n\over 1+f_n}\cdot 1_{[a,b]}.$ Then $g_{n,a,b}$ is increasing and bounded above by $1_{[a,b]}.$ If $g_{n,a,b}$ is convergent a.e. then $f_n$ is convergent a.e. on $[a,b]$ (possibly to $+\infty$ at some points $x$ if $g_{n,a,b}(x)$ tends to $1$).  As $[a,b]$ is arbitrary the sequence $f_n$ is convergent a.e.